# Help understanding a particular proof using recurrence relationship.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, mathematical-modeling

So i am working through a proof in a paper and so far have managed to obtain the expressions

$$f(x) = \frac{\theta\Gamma(J+1)\Gamma(J+\theta-x)}{x\Gamma(J+\theta)\Gamma(J+1-x)} \quad(1) $$

$$r = \sum_{x=1}^{J}f(x)  \quad(2)$$

Now in the paper i'm working through it somehow uses the fact that $$ \sum_{x=1}^Jxf(x) = J   \quad(3)$$ to obtain  recurrence  relationship

$$r(J+1) = r(J) + \frac{\theta}{\theta+J} (4) $$
And finished by using the fact that $r(1) = 1$ to find
$$r = \sum_{i=0}^{J-1}\frac{\theta}{\theta+i} \quad (5)$$

Now i understand how they got (1) (2) and (3) and i also understand how to get from (4) to (5). However i have no clue how they get to (4)

If it helps here is a link to the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.68.061902) or the [preprint](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00976654/document). The specific equation i'm trying to get to is (7) though most of the relevant information is in the Appendix.

Comment: As you wrote $(2)$ now, $r =Jf(x)$, is that what you intended?

Comment: Ah error noted and corrected